# Why does tidyr::crossing sort vectors?

Tags: r, tidyr

When creating Cartesian products using `tidyr::crossing` it seems that vectors get sorted, but tibbles do not. Is this a bug, or simply a consequence of the tidyverse not being very concerned about the order of rows?

For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(A = 1:2) %>%
  crossing(B = month.abb[1:2])
```

produces a tibble with column `B` having 'Feb' before 'Jan'. In contrast in

```
tibble(A = 1:2) %>%
  crossing(tibble(B = month.abb[1:2]))
```

'Jan' comes first.

[`R version 3.5.2 Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)` and `tidyr_0.8.3`.]

Comment: In both the cases, I get `Feb` first on `tidyr` `0.8.3.9000`.

Comment: I get results consistent with OP on version 0.8.2. I don't see this mentioned in the NEWS file, but seems like a bug that got fixed, perhaps inadvertently with other changes (there are a few mentions of `crossing` in the news, just not this specifically).

Comment: I also get results as in the question using tidyr 0.8.3, R 3.6.1, Windows 10.